KVM error on Proxmox ARM64 (RK3588) when trying to use multiple cores in VM
I'm running Proxmox VE 8.2.7 on a RK3588 ARM platform (with 4x Cortex-A76 + 4x Cortex-A55 cores) and am encountering issues when trying to configure a VM with multiple cores.
Error Message:
kvm: Failed to put registers after init: Invalid argument
start failed: QEMU exited with code 1

System Information

NanoPC-T6
OS: Debian 12
Proxmox VE: 8.2.7
CPU: RK3588 (4x Cortex-A76 + 4x Cortex-A55)
ProxMox image is provided by the SBC manufacturer

Working Configuration
The VM works with a single core using with this configuration:
bios: ovmf
boot: order=scsi0
cores: 1
cpu: host
sockets: 1
numa0: cpus=4

efidisk0: local:100/vm-100-disk-0.raw,size=64M
memory: 8192
name: ubuntu-server
net0: virtio=BC:24:11:AF:4A:3A,bridge=wan
scsi0: local:100/vm-100-disk-1.raw,size=64G
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=3f9ac33b-6bb8-4532-8ef5-924703044cb1

I'm aware that mixing little and big cores on heterogeneous CPUs isn't supported as of right now. Which is also in the SBC manufactures instructions for ProxMox.
But using NUMA to set the specific cores does generate the same error:
qm set 100 --cores 4 --sockets 1
qm set 100 --numa0 cpus=0-3

Is there a way to get multiple cores running?
I want to switch my home server running a few docker services to a more power-efficient machine and I had this SBC lying around.
